# Using jQuery-UI with BoilerPlateJS

Tags: boilerplatejs

How can I include JQuery-UI components with BoilerPlateJS? I have an web app that used jquery tabs, datepicker, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the jquery-ui script and css files on your application's index.html file, so all JQuery-UI components will be available globally.

Comment: I have tried that but I don't how to use it with BoilerPlateJS. I have tried to add a tab but not working!

Comment: How are you initializing your jquery-ui components ? I would initialize them on the activate method of your boilerplate component

Answer (score 0):

as @guigouz mentioned, you need to initialize your jqueryui elements in the activate method in the component, after your ui panel is created.

I added a jqueryui sample here https://github.com/slayerjay/boilerplatejs/tree/master/src/modules/sampleModule2/jqueryui